# Python insert array into string

Tags: python, arrays, string, string-concatenation

I'm trying to create new files based on my store_array list. If the name doesn't exist yet in directory then create a new one, then another, then another. I have 300 files I need to create.

```
store_array = ["1234567", "987654", "1919103039"]

if store_number == "1":

    continue
  print(store_number, file=open(r'C:\Users\hank\Desktop\project\json_' + [store_number] + '".json', 'w'))
```

TypeError: must be str, not list

I can get output with a simple print(store_number) but I need to concat the text from the array into my filename.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: This indentation isn't correct.

Comment: `file=open(r'C:\Users\hank\Desktop\project\json_' + store_number + '".json', 'w'))` ?

Comment: Why are you wrapping `store_number` (a string) into a list?

Comment: 'C:\Users\hank\Desktop\project\json_' + [store_number] + '".json', 'w', `[store number]` is a list, which is why error occurs.

Comment: okay so I removed the quotes from the numbers in the array. And it should be store_array instead of store_number. The question is how to insert text from an array into the filename/string.

Comment: Convert the list into a string using join: `to_store = ' '.join(store_array)`

Answer (score 0):

If the error is in the lack of an existing file, the following example may demonstrate a solution. It writes a blank json file for each str(number) in a list.

```
import json, os

placeholder_data = {}
store_array = ["1","2","3"]

for store_number in store_array:
    filename = os.path.join('C:\users\csind\documents\pscripts','test{}.json'.format(store_number))

    with open(filename,'w') as file:
        json.dump(placeholder_data,file)

    print(store_number, filename)
```

Comment: I see where you're going with this but still receiving an error. I'm on Python3 if that matters. 1 <_io.TextIOWrapper name=

Comment: I am confused. Do you want each item of the the list (such as "1919103039") to be inserted into the file name? Because on python3, my second option given should totally work.

Comment: I want json_1 to be one filename. Then json_987654 to be another file name, etc.

Comment: Yeah, my answer should definitely work. What error are you getting?

Comment: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory. Which is odd since this is the exact same directory as all of my other projects. I've tried doublequotes too. Does it matter that I used store_number in the file AND store_number in the print line? I really appreciate the help so far!